# Javascript IF/Else in GTM Variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-tag-manager

I am trying to use GTM & custom Javascript to dynamically insert structured mark-up to a page depending on the text that is displayed at a certain position on the page (this changes every few weeks).

To do this I am trying to use If/Else but it results in undefined each time.
If have already created a variable that is working correctly and pulling the required text from the page {{EventLocationVariable}}.

I have so far:

```html
function () {
  
  var eventloc = {{EventLocationVariable}};
var customeventloc;

if (eventloc === Manchester) {
 customeventloc = 'Manchester details goes here';
}
else 
  if (eventloc === Liverpool) {
   customeventloc = 'Liverpool details goes here';
  }
else
  if (eventloc === Leeds) {
    customeventloc = 'Leeds details goes here';
  }
else
  if (eventloc === Birmingham) {
    customeventloc = 'Birmingham details goes here';
  }
else {
  customeventloc = 'some other details goes here';
}

return customeventloc;

}
```

This might be straightforward, but I just can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: This would be much more readable if you used a switch statement instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch. Also you are missing the quotes on you city names, whch means they are used as (undefined) variables instead of as literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, you're missing out on gold. What you actually need is a Lookup Table, and the {{EventLocationVariable}} you already have. Here:

[image: GTM - Lookup Table Example]

When you work with GTM, make sure you're thoroughly familiar with all its tag/variable/trigger types. The tendency to code your way to the solution may be great, particularly if you're from a JavaScript background, but GTM is great at offering simpler solutions.

Comment: Haha, can't believe I did not think of this. This should be definitely marked as the answer.

Comment: That's brilliant! I didn't know about Lookup Tables, I can't believe I haven't come across these sooner in all my searches. That's going to make things easier going forward.

Comment: Glad to be of help. :) And thanks for marking this as the answer. My first ever on SO. GTM has quite a lot of built-in stuff like this, but it doesn't seem to invest much in making sure that the developers know about them all.

Answer (score 0):

You needed a function names, and quotes for sure.

Here is a simpler version

ES5

```js
const cust = {
  'Manchester': 'Manchester details goes here',
  'Liverpool': 'Liverpool details goes here',
  'Leeds': 'Leeds details goes here',
  'Birmingham': 'Birmingham details goes here'
};

const getCustomEvent = function(eventloc) { return  cust[eventloc] || 'some other details goes here'; };


//const ce = getCustomEvent("{{EventLocationVariable}}"); // uncomment when happy
const ce = getCustomEvent("Leeds"); // remove when happy
console.log(ce)
// testing non-existing event
console.log(getCustomEvent("Nope"))
```

ES6

```js
const cust = {
  'Manchester': 'Manchester details goes here',
  'Liverpool': 'Liverpool details goes here',
  'Leeds': 'Leeds details goes here',
  'Birmingham': 'Birmingham details goes here'
};

const getCustomEvent = eventloc => cust[eventloc] || 'some other details goes here';


//const ce = getCustomEvent("{{EventLocationVariable}}"); // uncomment when happy
const ce = getCustomEvent("Leeds"); // remove when happy
console.log(ce)
// testing non-existing event
console.log(getCustomEvent("Nope"))
```

Comment: GTM does not support arrow functions (or any ES6 features) in custom variables.

Comment: Uunfortunately GTM throws up lots of errors with this, along the lines of what @eike mentioned. But adding quotes to the city names has got it working now, although it may not be pretty. Thanks!